# ElasticSearch: check how analyzers/tokenizers/filters applied to an index split text into tokens?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-analyzers

I'm quite new to ElasticSearch, so if I overlook something obvious/basic, please forgive me.

Now I'm using ElasticSearch at work, and want to see how the complex settings of analyzers/tokenizers/filters--which are set by my predecessors--split texts into tokens.

I did some research and found the way to do it:

```
GET /_analyze
{
  "tokenizer" : "whitespace",
  "filter" : ["lowercase", {"type": "stop", "stopwords": ["a", "is", "this"]}],
  "text" : "this is a test"
}
```

However, as I said, the settings of analyzers/tokenizers/filters is so complicated that writing the details every time I test the settings would horribly slow me down.

So I want to analyze a text **with analyzers/tokenizers/filters settings already applied to an index**. Is there way to do that?

I would appreciate it if anyone would shed some lights on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to supply the complete analyzer definition every time to analyze API, you can simply use the `_analyze` API on index and use it like following

```
GET <your-index-name>/_analyze
{
  "analyzer" : "standard",
  "text" : "Quick Brown Foxes!"
}
```

**So instead of using the analyze API at a cluster level, you will be using it on index level**, where analyzer definition is already present, so you just need to provide the `analyzer` name not its definition like `filter` etc to get the tokens based on the analyzer.

Refer Elasticsearch official documentation on using it on [specific index](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-analyze.html#analyze-api-specific-index-ex) or on a [specific field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-analyze.html#analyze-api-field-ex) with examples.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for sharing great information again! You really saved my day. By the way, is there way to provide multiple analyzer names into a query? Looks like my predecessors applied multiple analyzers(kuromoji/n-gram) to an index……

Comment: @NullableYogurt can you please ask a followup question with all the details ? also don't forget to mark this answer accepted :) and I am glad my answer helping you and community :)

Comment: Defenitely. Sorry for my unfamiliar reaction. I'll make a new question soon.

Comment: @NullableYogurt thats ok, its just very difficult to put all the info in the comments, also its not related to this question so would not be useful for others also :)